# Verify my solution of the Alternating Series test

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Suppose we have a series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{n^2}{10^n} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n b_n$$.

I want to apply the alternating series test to see if it converges.

I need to show that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{10^n} = 0$$

$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{10^{n+1}} \leq \frac{n^2}{10^n}$$

To see that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{10^n} =0$, we note that the denominator is going to grow way faster than the the numerator. If you want to show it using calculus, then you can do L'hoptials rule twice to get:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2}{10^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{10^xlog^2(10)}=0$

Next we want to know if

$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{10^{n+1}} \leq \frac{n^2}{10^n}$$

is true for all $n$. Rearranging, we can get:

$$\frac{10^n}{10^{n+1}} \leq \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{10} \leq \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}= (\frac{n}{n+1})^2$$

By plugging in values $n=2,3,...$ we can see that this inequality only gets more and more true as $n$ gets bigger since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{n}{n+1})^2 = 1$

To show this with calculus we consider the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{10^x}$ and take it's derivative and find when it is $\leq 0$ on our domain of interest $[2, \infty)$:

$f'(x) = -10^{-x}x(xlog(10)-2) \leq 0$

This will be true as long as $(xlog(10)-2)$ is not negative, so $x \geq \frac{2}{log(10)}$, whicn includes our domain since we only care about $[2, \infty)$

Thus the series converges by the alternating series test

Comment: I haven't checked the details but it feels correct to me. The point of the AST is that even if the sequence $(|a_n|)$ converges very slowly to $0$, so that it's series diverges, the original alternating sequence $(a_n)$ converges (not necessarily to $0$ though). In your question, your sequence converges quite rapidly to $0$, so it's "obvious" that the alternating series will converge, and in fact it will converge quite rapidly.

Comment: I believe the alternating series test is due to Leibniz in the 17th Century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to show that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\frac{1}{10} \leq \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\ \forall \ n \geq N,\ $ is to just decompose $\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}$ by partial fractions.

$\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} = 1 - \left(\frac{2}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$. Let $m=n+1$, so that we may write:

$\frac{2}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{2}{m} - \frac{1}{m^2}$.

$\frac{2}{m} - \frac{1}{m^2} < \frac{2}{m} \leq \frac{2}{3} \ \forall \ m \geq 3.$ Changing back into $n$'s,

$1 - \left(\frac{2}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) > \frac{1}{3} \ \forall \ n \geq 2$

I have shown that $\frac{1}{10} < \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \forall \ n \geq 2$.

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{(n+1)^2}{10^n} ( >0 ), $ we get: $\frac{(n+1)^2}{10^{n+1}} < \frac{n^2}{10^n}$. Replacing the stronger $<$ with the weaker $ \leq $ is fine, and we get the desired inequality for (all) $n \geq 2$.

Comment: You can probably do even better, because when $n=1, \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{4} >  \frac{1}{10}$, but there's no need.

Answer (score 0):

When using the ratio test, you should evaluate $\frac{|f(n+1)|}{|f(n)|}$ and then explain what the result of that means, rather than assuming that the series will or won't converge and writing the inequality $|f(n+1)|<|f(n)|$ (or $>$)

In this case, we have that $$\frac{|f(n+1)|}{|f(n)|}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{10^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^2}{10^n}}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{10n^2}\to\frac{1}{10}<1$$
so the series converges.

Comment: I actually didn't use the ratio test here, the two things in the middle are what need to be confirmed in order to draw a conclusion from "The alternating series test"

Comment: @Rhys Hughes - Well this shows that the absolute series converges, therefore the alternative series diverges, yes. But that wasn't the question.

Comment: I was merely focussing on the step where the ratio test appears to be used, correcting the minor error of assuming $f(n+1)\leq f(n)$ rather than evaluating $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ without any assumptions.

Comment: Oh yeah I totally missed that the first time. He's assumed the conclusion and gone from there. Yeah that's fine to do that in your initial working but you need to reverse the process in your answer OP.